# Linux: can't open /dev/dsp

Tags: linux, audio, festival

I am getting an error while running `festival` on my system: `linux: can,t open /dev/dsp`

I was searching for this error on the Internet and found this instruction:

> To solve this problem just write this `.festivalrc` in your home directory or `/usr/share/festival/festival.scm`
>
> ```
> (Parameter.set 'Audio_Command "aplay -q -c 1 -t raw -f s16 -r $SR $FILE")
> (Parameter.set 'Audio_Method 'Audio_Command)
> ```

but I don't have any document named `.festivalrc` in my home directory. I created a document in my home directory with file name `.festivalrc`
and I copied above two lines in that document and saved it, but `festival` is still not working.

Please can anyone tell me right steps to solve this problem

Comment: try run festival as root... if it works maybe you need to add audio group to your user

Answer (score 1):

You can find festival.scm file in `/etc/festival.scm` if you have installed festival through apt install.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but I arrived here having the same problem when trying to use Octave's audio input. I found a solution on the [Notes of a Programmer blog](http://notesofaprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/09/audio-playing-and-recording-with-octave.html).

In brief: "OSS version 3 was the original sound system for Linux, but was superseded by the Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (or ALSA) in 2002" ([2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Open_Sound_System)). If you are using ALSA, `/dev/dsp` does not exist, as it was part of OSS. However, it can be emulated using the [alsa-oss package](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Aoss), which works as a wrapper.